# How to create a Pandas Dataframe that uses previous rows like a trigger event?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried this code but isn't doing what I wanted it to do.  I'm try to get events to work on a pandas dataframe.  If the Expiration Date equals the index date, then I want a value of 0.  If the prediction column shows a 1 then I would like to get a 1 value.  I would like it to check previous row if a 1 was already trigger that it stays 1 until the Expiration Date triggers a 0.

```
df['Forecast'] = np.select([df.ExpirationDate == df.index,
                         df.Predictions == 1,
                         df.Forecast.shift(1).eq(1)], [0, 1, 1])
```

I tried shift but it doesn't seem to work properly as it only does it once.

```
                 Open        High  ...  ExpirationDate  Predictions
Date                                ...                             
2017-09-18  249.610001  250.119995  ...      2017-10-20            0
2017-09-19  250.000000  250.070007  ...      2017-10-20            0
2017-09-20  250.070007  250.190002  ...      2017-10-20            0
2017-09-21  249.880005  249.979996  ...      2017-10-20            0
2017-09-22  249.050003  249.630005  ...      2017-10-20            0
```

Expected output

```
            Predictions  Forecast  
Date                               
2017-09-18            0         0  
2017-09-19            0         0  
2017-09-20            0         0  
2017-09-21            0         0  
2017-09-22            0         0  
2017-09-25            0         0  
2017-09-26            0         0  
2017-09-27            0         0  
2017-09-28            0         0  
2017-09-29            0         0  
2017-10-02            0         0  
2017-10-03            0         0  
2017-10-04            0         0  
2017-10-05            1         1  
2017-10-06            0         1  
2017-10-09            0         1  
2017-10-10            0         1  
2017-10-11            0         1  
2017-10-12            0         1  
2017-10-13            0         1  
2017-10-16            0         1  
2017-10-17            0         1  
2017-10-18            0         1  
2017-10-19            0         1  
2017-10-20            0         0
```

So, Forecast stays 1 after a 1 in predictions is present.  Forecast would turn back to 0 when the expiration is present.

Comment: can you post your expected output?

Comment: I hope the expected output helps explain what I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 3):

We can also use [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) + [`Series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
df['Forecast']=(

df['Predictions'].cumsum()
                 .clip(0,1)
                 .where(df.index < df.ExpirationDate)
                 .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
            Predictions ExpirationDate  Forecast
Date                                            
2017-09-18            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-19            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-20            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-21            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-22            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-25            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-26            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-27            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-28            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-29            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-10-02            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-10-03            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-10-04            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-10-05            1     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-06            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-09            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-10            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-11            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-12            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-13            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-16            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-17            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-18            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-19            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-20            0     2017-10-20         0
```

Comment: This is really close.  The only problem is when Date is the same date as Expiration Date the Forecast is still getting a 1 and not a 0.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Series.where` to mask, allowing for forward filling with `fillna`. Another `where` sets the values only prior to the expiration Date for each row and we set the remaining values back to 0.

```
df['Forecast'] = (df['Predictions'].where(df.Predictions.eq(1))
                       .ffill()
                       .where(df.index < df.ExpirationDate)
                       .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))
```

---

```
            Predictions ExpirationDate  Forecast
Date                                            
2017-09-18            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-19            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-20            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-21            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-22            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-25            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-26            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-27            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-28            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-09-29            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-10-02            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-10-03            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-10-04            0     2017-10-20         0
2017-10-05            1     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-06            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-09            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-10            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-11            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-12            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-13            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-16            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-17            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-18            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-19            0     2017-10-20         1
2017-10-20            0     2017-10-20         0
```

Comment: This answer was really close too and had the same problem as it doesn't give 0 when the expiration date is the same  index date.

Comment: @frostd the check is < so the same date should get `NaN`’d by the second where. Are you sure you aren’t using <= or have a time component to either part of the dates? You can see in my example 2017-10-20 is 0.

Comment: yes it is < and not <=. What do you mean have a time? ExpirationDate is non null object. I get errors when I try to changed ExpirationDate to a datetime object or to a string. https://photos.app.goo.gl/WEHPLf7ewi8LZSd78 This is what the dataframe looks like so far.  Thanks a lot, I appreciate all the help.